# Data conversion or data mapping error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

This is my WinSQL query that I try and execute.

```
SELECT ezait6 AS "MO No",
       vhitno AS "Item No",
       vhrefd AS "Finish Date",
       vhmaqa AS "Manuf Qty",
       vhmaun AS "U/M"
FROM m3edbtest.mwohed,
     m3edbtest.cinacc
WHERE ezcono = 1
      AND vhcono = ezcono
      AND vhrefd >= '20170801'
      AND vhrefd <= '20170831'
      AND vhmfno = ezait6;
```

--Different Data Types

--vhmfno ==> Integer

--ezait6 ==> nchar(8)

After I run my query, I got below errors:

```
-- Error : SQL0802 - Data conversion or data mapping error.
```

I suspect that it is beclose of different data type
I have a nvarchar column in one of my table "ezait6". 
So how should I convert that values to INT type.

Comment: you can vhmfno=CONVERT(INT,ezait6), but it will throw an exception if ezait6 have not only numeric data.

Comment: Use above comment suggation also Make alias of table put aleas name.column name for every column might be it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Seems like you need to adjust your table definitions... (If you want to join Integer with nchar(8), something is wrong.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You can check first if the content of the varchar field is numeric and query only on those:

```
SELECT ezait6 AS "MO No",
       vhitno AS "Item No",
       vhrefd AS "Finish Date",
       vhmaqa AS "Manuf Qty",
       vhmaun AS "U/M"
FROM m3edbtest.mwohed,
     m3edbtest.cinacc
WHERE IsNumeric(ezait6)=1
      AND ezcono = 1
      AND vhcono = ezcono
      AND vhrefd >= '20170801'
      AND vhrefd <= '20170831'
      AND vhmfno = CONVERT(INT,ezait6);
```

Comment: Is the server a MSSQL instance ?

Comment: No. WinSql only

Comment: You can check without the IsNumeric, only with the CONVERT part. But it's unsafe. If CONVERT is not enabled check CAST(ezait6 as INTEGER)

Comment: If I use CAST(ezait6 as INTEGER), same error come out.